# how to get latex to render in ms word equation env?

Tags: ms-word, latex, ms-office

According to the [MS Word documentation on equation markup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8), selecting "LaTeX" and clicking convert is all that is necessary to render the code.  However, I tried this (with and without dollar signs shown below) and nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: I suspect whoever wrote that page is not very familiar with LaTeX and nor am I. But...AFAIK clicking on the LaTeX option *at the end* is probably not going to help. Click at the beginning, ditch the LaTeX $$ "bracketing" (you don't need \( )\ either), and ignore the statement that Word implements "most" latex expressions. AFAICS Word just doesn't recognise "intercal" and you would need to add something like U+22A4 DOWN TACK or U+22BA INTERCALATE instead (you can use Word insert symbol, or you could add a Math AutoCorrect). I don't know if the pipe symbol has special meaning in LaTeX...

Comment: ...and I can't see past "intercal$_" in the image you posted, so don't know if there's more.